# Weighted kruskal wallis

Tags: python, weighted, kruskal-wallis

I am working on python on a dataset containing id, id nationality (EU,US,other) , a weight (probability of being of a certain nationality) and id salary.
I may have an id repeated twice based on the weight.

The aim is to use a Kruskal Wallis test (on id salary and nationality) 
My great doubt is: how can l do this if scipy function for kruskal does not allow me to deal with weights?

I know that in R there is wtd_mwd function but l can not find anything similar in Python

Comment: where can i find `wtd_mwd` ?

Comment: Here’s the link: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjstats/reference/wtd_sd.html